# Problem Understanding Logical X and Z operators

Tags: stabilizer-code

I am trying to understand the concept of Logical X and Z operators. That ${\bar{X}}$ and ${\bar{Z}}$, if that is what it is called. [image]

I have multiple questions regarding this diagram. Help me understand wrt this figure and also if possible give some example:-

1. How is that ${\bar{X}}$ and ${\bar{Z}}$ is calculated or found ?
2. How is the ${\bar{X}}$ and ${\bar{Z}}$ different from the generators - IIIXXXX, IXXIIXX, XIXIXIX, etc. or is it any different?
3. What is the meaning of the last line of fig. "Logical ${\bar{X}}$ and ${\bar{Z}}$ is TRANSVERSAL" ?
4. Is the ${\bar{X}}$ and ${\bar{Z}}$ also called as "Encoded X and Z operators"

Comment: each post should contain a single, laser-focused question. Feel free to edit your post to focus it on a specific point and ask the other questions on separate posts

Answer (score 1):

(1) The operators $\bar X$ and $\bar Z$ are found by requiring two operators that (i) commute with all the stabilizers and (ii) cannot be expressed as a product of the stabilizers. Note that the two will anti-commute with each other.

The way that I would do this computationally is to fill in an $M\times 2N$ binary matrix, where $M$ is the number of generators you have, and $N$ is the number of qubits they act on. Each row corresponds to a different generator, and you fill in 0/1 for the first $N$ entries depending on if there's an $X$ present on that qubit. Similarly for the second $N$, you do the same but with $Z$ operators. Remember that $Y$ contains both $X$ and $Z$. Once you've found that matrix, you can find the null space (modulo 2).

(2) These are different from the generators, as specified in my answer to part (1).

(3) Transversal gates are ones which can be realised by applying individual rotations on each of the qubits of the code.

(4) I suppose they can be. Logical is the word more typically used rather than encoded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to make the circuit for the Steane code. But I am having 2 questions. What is the use of logical ${\bar{X}}$ and ${\bar{Z}}$ in the circuit ? I know the generators are used to detect errors. I see in this video [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vTadpnDiS0] at 29:53, the left ones are the generators I see, but is the right X's and Z's in that is the same logical ${\bar{X}}$ and ${\bar{Z}}$. ?

Comment: Let's say you want to use an error correcting code. This is not just for storage, but you want to compute. What you should not do is decode the qubit, perform a gate, and encode it again because you lose all the noise protection. Instead, you need to perform the gate directly on the logical qubit. $\bar X$ and $\bar Z$ are there to implement the Pauli $X$ and $Z$ gates on the logical qubit.

Comment: As for your second question, no, those are not the logical operations. Those are the corrections that you have to perform depending on the different outcomes of the syndrome measurements so that you can correct for errors (again, without decoding the qubit first)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if I understood it correctly, in case of actual circuit implementation there is no concept of logical X and Z. In that case the stabilizers are there. So the logical X and Z is a theoretical concept ?

Comment: There's very much a real circuit implementation of logical $X$. You just apply $X$ on each of the individual qubits.